# How to install pip on Terminal on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am running MacOS Catalina.When you install Python you automatically get pip.  After I downloaded the latest version of Python onto my Mac, I then went into the Terminal to check if pip was installed.  At that point, I realized that every command I typed into the terminal didn't work.  The main error I would get back is "syntax incorrect".  Is there a certain way to type commands into Terminal on Mac?

Comment: The phrase "syntax incorrect" looks odd; no shell I'm aware of would say that. What commands are you typing, and what are the actual error messages?

Comment: How did you install Python?  Did you have to manually change your PATH, and therefore maybe had to edit your .bash_profile or .bashrc file?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the latest version of `python`. Then you should be able to access both `python` and `pip` with:

```
python3
```

or

```
pip3
```

This is because on Mac you get `python 2` included by default. So when you install `Python 3`, it doesn't overwrite your existing installation. So it sets a new path inside your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` for `pip3` and `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you accidentally did `pip` or if your console isn't working so let me try to give two solutions. 1: if you use `pip` it will not work properly as mac does not auto-install python 2.7, instead use `pip3 install #package`.

If your console isn't working use `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin"` to reset your console path then open `.bash_profile` and make changes accordingly.